# TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got Ellipsis

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_list_from_tuple(board: Tuple[Tuple[Optional[int], ...], ...]) -> List[List[Optional[int], ...], ...]:
    return list(list(x) for x in board)
```

Why am I getting the error "TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got Ellipsis." for this function??

Comment: Because they have to be types, and the ellipsis isn’t a type. What did you *want* the ellipsis to mean?

Answer (score 3):

Because Ellipsis is (currently) only valid as an argument when defining a variable-length *tuple* - not on a List declaration. See the typing documentation for Tuple at https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple.

Your signature should probably be:

```
def get_list_from_tuple(board: Tuple[Tuple[Optional[int], ...], ...]) -> List[List[Optional[int]]]:
```